# Houzz add button in facybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to add "Houzz Add" button on each image showing in **fancybox** popup.
i placed code provided by houzz in beforeShow function to show the link with each image but popup is showing the button only for first image and simple link on others which redirect to Houzz.com

is there any way i can have the Add button on every image in popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code to integrate social site links also like facebook,twitter,pinterest with houzz
similar code can be used to integrate other buttons also.

```
beforeShow: function () {
if (this.title) { 
    this.title += '<br />';
    //----Twitter button------//
    this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';
    //----pinterest (pin it)------//
    this.title += '<a class="pin-it-button" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+encodeURIComponent(document.location.href)+'&media='+encodeURIComponent('http://absoluteimagepath.com/path/to/image/'+this.href)+'&description=Pin from ScottGale.com">'+'<img title="Pin It" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" alt="" border="0" /></a>';
  //----Facebook like------//
    this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='+this.href+'&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
  //----Houzz button------//
    this.title += '<iframe width="48" scrolling="no" height="20" frameborder="0" style="border: medium none;" src="http://www.houzz.com/buttonWidget/1?url='+this.href+'&img='+this.href+'&title=YourTitle&hzid=YourHouzzID&ref=http://yourdomain"></iframe>';
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by additionally embedding the SCRIPT tags for each button **every time** you dynamically create them. This will re-run the JavaScript that converts the A tags into Houzz Buttons.

The Houzz servers will verify metadata through a backend CURL request (similar to Facebook's Like Button) so be sure that the links your FancyBox Houzz Buttons point to have Houzz buttons embedded in their own **static** HTML pages as well.

Hope this helps!

Web Developer Documentation: http://www.houzz.com/buttonsAndBadges#houzzbutton